# Resize the layout when the keyboard opens

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I want to resize my activity layout when the soft keyboard opens.
I tried putting this in the manifest :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

but it doesn't work. And this is my xml layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ui.SettingsActivity">

    <!-- BODY -->
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewBody"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- my list -->

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <!-- TOOLBAR -->
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

Layout does not resize when keyboard opens...
Help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element)

> **"adjustResize"**
> The activity's main window is always resized to make
> room for the soft keyboard on screen.
>
> **"adjustPan"**
> The activity's main
> window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the
> contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current
> focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what
> they are typing. This is generally less desirable than resizing,
> because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to get at and
> interact with obscured parts of the window.

I believe what you want is **adjustPan**.